# Запятая перед "и" (синтаксис)

Tags: синтаксис

> Правду говорят: нельзя делать два дело одновременно(,) и делать их
> хорошо.

Сомневаюсь, присоединительный союз здесь или нет?
Есть вариант, что здесь однородное соподчинение придаточных, но тогда запятая будет не нужна.

Comment: делать два дело?

Comment: Опять приняли неверный ответ. Здесь "нельзя" общее.

Comment: Здесь могу вам сразу рассказать: присоединение всегда можно оформить новым предложением, а здесь ерунда получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение, которое вы приводите в качестве примера, представляет собой сложносочиненное предложение с присоединительными отношениями. Об этом свидетельствуют характерная пауза после первой части, смысловая законченность первого предложения, а также лексический повтор во второй части. Союз и выражает добавочное, попутное замечание здесь.

Comment: Тогда можно было бы написать так: *Правду говорят: нельзя делать два дело одновременно. И делать их хорошо.*

Comment: А это уже парцелляция.

Comment: Это не подходит, потому что там единая фраза. И там о том, что говорят. Какой смысл добавлять, что ещё говорят? Разве что если человек потом вспомнил. Оно объединяется не только словом "нельзя", а и "правду говорят".

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это точно не присоединительные отношения, потому что без сочетания ‟и делать хорошо” предложение не является завершённым по смыслу из-за слова ‟нельзя” – нельзя делать два дела и делать хорошо. Присоединение – это такое сочетание, которое не задумывалось до начала произношения предложения и которым человек решает дополнить предложение уже в процессе произношения. То, что здесь есть более длинная пауза после первого однородного, – это обычное дело, когда первое однородное является распространённым или есть какие-то дополнительные слова перед ‟и”. Взгляните на пример: ‟Я съел оба этих бутерброда одновременно и пошёл спать”. Такая же пауза, как и в предложении в вопросе.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146356/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Не могу написать комментарий под ответом из-за рейтинга. Вот вам не стыдно такое писать, а? Повтор слов – это присоединение. Я надеюсь, что кто-нибудь напишет это под вашим ответом.

Comment: Это я для вас написала. чтобы вы их увидели, а то не догадаетесь и опять не поймете.  Рекомендую вам вести себя прилично и воздержаться от личностных оценок в грубой форме. а то модератор уже близко...

Comment: Первый пример – это ССП, а во втором примере возможна двоякая пунктуация. При таком повторе слов 99, 99999999 процентов случаев не ставится запятая. Повтор слов не значит присоединение, это просто нелепо.

Comment: Да не переживайте вы так, бог с ним, с повтором. Это всего лишь мое наблюдение, хотела с вами поделиться. А вот  Розенталь самый настоящий, и он против вас.

Comment: Вы здесь правы. Sharon написал.

Answer (score 2):

Даже если рассматривать заданный пример в рамках однородных членов (а не ССП, так как это спорный в лингвистике вопрос), все равно там будут **присоединительные отношения**, что определяется **повтором** слов:

*Правду говорят: нельзя **делать** два дела одновременно, и **делать** их хорошо*.

В качестве примера можно привести предложения из Розенталя ([§ 24. Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)):

*Об этом ведутся **споры**, и **споры** горячие.*
*Нужно **идти** вперёд, и **идти** как можно быстрее.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146547/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.